# Is it possible to suppress gen 2 GC collection in .NET?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

My program allocates a very large number of instances that comprise a long-lived DAWG. During the construction of this DAWG, there are times when the progress slows down 100 fold, and this correlates perfectly with .NET performing gen 2 GC collections. During these periods, the "% time in GC" is 99.5%, and the "total gen 2 collections" increments every few seconds. After *several back-to-back gen 2 collections*, they stop triggering for no obvious reason and the program speeds up again. A few minutes later, the cycle restarts.

The number of instances I create is on the order of 25 million, and they take up several GB of RAM, so it's not too surprising that the gen 2 collections take this long. What is surprising is that gen 2 collections come in "trains", and get triggered continually.

Can I somehow prevent this without completely rethinking my approach? Perhaps there's some way to ask .NET to suspend gen 2 collections until further notice? The program runs very efficiently apart from these occurrences, so .NET is clearly quite up to this task apart from this unfortunate corner-case behaviour.

(I tried setting GCSettings.LatencyMode to GCLatencyMode.Batch, but the issue remained. The amount of free physical RAM at the time the GCs start happening is around 1GB. This is on a 64-bit machine.)

Comment: "So, don't _do_ that". Seriously, maybe it's time to get "old school" and use, say, five arrays with 25Million entries, rather than 25 Million instances with five properties each?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Maybe, and I have investigated that approach. Because C# doesn't allow pointers to structs that contain managed types (arrays, in my case), this entails a **severe** drop in maintainability, because everything is now an index instead of a reference to the target class.

Comment: This is one of those issues whose severity is difficult to communicate well — other people have to experience the issue before they will sympathise with the gravity of the problem...

Comment: @romkyns the struct array/index approach **is** the only way to do this conveniently, though. Anything else is *worse* (unmanaged memory, etc). See mine and Sam's blog entries on this subject: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html and http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/10/28/in-managed-code-we-trust-our-recent-battles-with-the-net-garbage-collector

Comment: @Timwi: I know the severity. It's just very clear it's time to bite the bullet. Wrap the ugly in an abstraction, but wrap it. This is not premature optimization. It's time to optimize this into something that can possibly work. 25M little instances is outside the design center for CLR memory management.

Comment: @Marc thanks, looks right on the mark. Given that the DAWG is very cleanly separable from the rest of the C# code, and that the struct array approach pretty much entails managing my own memory anyway, I think this might be a time when dropping down to C++/CLI is actually a better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 4.5+ you can specify your preference for fewer Gen 2 collections by using the new `GCLatencyMode` options.

```
GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency;
```

More info here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx

> **My app cannot tolerate pauses during a certain time window**
>
> A growing subset of .NET developers has built commercial apps and
>   services that deliver results according to defined business
>   requirements or SLAs. Stock markets are examples of services that must
>   deliver very timely results while markets are open. Typically, these
>   apps perform significant work during the time when they want to
>   deliver low-latency results. Yet they cannot tolerate noticeable
>   pauses due to a collection.
>
> Our customers have told us that they would deploy more memory on their
>   servers if doing so would remove long pause times (which are typically
>   introduced by full blocking GCs). In the .NET Framework 4.5, we
>   provided that option by introducing SustainedLowLatency mode, which
>   avoids full blocking GCs. This mode is also available for the
>   workstation GC in the .NET Framework 4 via Update 4.0.3.
>
> While the SustainedLowLatency setting is in effect, generation 0,
>   generation 1, and background generation 2 collections still occur and
>   do not typically cause noticeable pause times. A blocking generation 2
>   collection happens only if the machine is low in memory or if the app
>   induces a GC by calling GC.Collect(). It is critical that you deploy
>   apps that use the SustainedLowLatency setting onto machines that have
>   adequate memory, so they will satisfy the resulting growth in the heap
>   while the setting is in effect.
>
> In the .NET Framework 4.5, SustainedLowLatency mode is available for
>   both workstation and server GC. To turn it on, set the
>   GCSettings.LatencyMode property to GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency.
>   The .NET Framework 4 includes a LowLatency mode for workstation GC;
>   however, this setting is only intended to be used for short periods of
>   time, whereas SustainedLowLatency mode is intended to be used for much
>   longer.

There is also `NoGCRegion` that you can try.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gclatencymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Indicates that garbage collection is suspended while the app is
>   executing a critical path. NoGCRegion is a read-only value; that is,
>   you cannot assign the NoGCRegion value to the GCSettings.LatencyMode
>   property. You specify the no GC region latency mode by calling the
>   TryStartNoGCRegion method and terminate it by calling the
>   EndNoGCRegion method.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from .NET 4.6 you can 'attempt to disallow' garbage collection in a code region by using the GC.TryStartNoGCRegion and GC.EndNoGCRegion methods.

```
try
{
    GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(TOTAL_SIZE, true);

    <No GC region code here>
}   
finally
{
    if (GCSettings.LatencyMode == GCLatencyMode.NoGCRegion) GC.EndNoGCRegion();
}
```

For more info on the arguments and possible exception see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906202(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, there is still no guarantee that GC will not be called. If for example you are using some library in 'No GC region code' and that library calls GC.Collect(), not only that the garbage collection will occur but also exception will be thrown by GC.EndNoGCRegion().

I am afraid you will have to rethink your approach as .NET garbage collection does not seem to be built (as of .NET 4.6) to handle millions of allocated objects with complex relationships between them. NFX library mentioned in one of the posts here is an option as well as using structures, simplifying model to reduce relations, use indexes into arrays instead of references etc.

Comment: The `TryStartNoGCRegion` needs to be outside the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

We had the similar issue with caching social+routing data.
We had to cache hundreds of millions of entries as storing this out-of-process was not fast enough due to network traffic (even on local host).
Instead we created a special 100% managed memory manager that allocates byte[] segments and the sub-allots the space there. The objects from CLR heap are turned into "PilePointers{int segment, int address}" via a special binary serialization which is orders of magnitude faster than BinaryFormatter. So now, the object graph of any complexity and size may be stored for a LOMG TIME in the managed heap, yet GC blocking pause < 10 ms, full GC is around 30-60 ms.

We store **300,000,000 objects easily on a 64Gb PC**, and the most interesting part of it is this: **the solution works WAY FASTER than storing objects in an un-managed heap** via Marshal or out-of-process via redis/memcache.

See this:
Pile:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUBF2Ncvbbs

Cache:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz_7hukyejQ

Get the code (Apache 2):
https://github.com/aumcode/nfx

Answer (score -3):

#### No.

You can't suppress it because it's **necessary** to *guarantee* the correctness of the program (at least so far as the framework is concerned).

Simply put, the CLR doesn't let you live this dangerously. If you need manual memory management, then you have to make your own data structures out of `struct`s, and manage everything manually.

---

That said, 25 million is a lot of objects, but it shouldn't be several gigabytes unless your objects are also relatively large. Can you use arrays of structs instead of classes to avoid the extra references? Is there any information you can remove?

Comment: Any references? Since when is GC necessary to guarantee correctness? Is my program incorrect during the minutes when no gen 2 GCs occur?

Comment: That is explicitly false.  The null GC is fully valid, from a specificational point of view.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx

Comment: @romkyns: I said guarantee correctness *at least so far as the framework is concerned* -- in other words, the GC is designed to simulate infinite memory for your program as well as possible, and as such, it would remove this guarantee on your program (and hence jeopardize its correctness) if it allowed for disabling itself.

Comment: @SLaks: The null GC is **only valid** if there is no need for clean-up. In this case, though, there certainly *is* a need, so the null GC isn't valid.

Comment: @Mehrdad Firstly, there is *no need* to clean up; the gen 2 GC doesn't clean up anything; all the long-lived objects remain alive. Secondly, not removing junk is not invalid if you don't run out of memory - and I don't.

Comment: @romkyns: That's because you know *a priori* what's going to happen. The obviously GC doesn't, so it tries to clean up because it's pretty confident that allocating objects at such a high rate jeopardizes the program. So it puts all its effort into making sure your program has as much memory as needed to run correctly.

Comment: True, which is why I was hoping I could give it a hand. There's nothing wrong with clever algorithms that sometimes need a hand. The GC already provides several ways in which I could give it hints, so it was not an unreasonable assumption that there might be a way to nudge it in the right direction in my situation.

Comment: @romkyns: Oh of course -- I wasn't saying it was unreasonable, I was just explaining why it isn't possible in .NET (strong framework guarantees = less custom control). :)